# Notification Center not working. The observer is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to call a function from another class in Swift and `NotificationCenter` is an option to do that so I started with the  `addObserver`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu), name: NSNotification.Name("callToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
}

@objc func toggleSideMenu(){
    if isMenuOpen {
        sideContainer.constant = -260
    } else {
        sideContainer.constant = 0
    }
}
```

And in the other class I have added the (post):

```
@objc func clickOnButton(button: UIButton) {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("callToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
}
```

Everything seems ok but I do not know why it is not working. I have seen a lot of the same issue here in stackoverflow but no answer solved my issue.

Comment: is `addObserver` called before the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function definition is not correct. It should be :

```
@objc func toggleSideMenu(_ notification: Notification){
    if isMenuOpen {
        sideContainer.constant = -260
    } else {
        sideContainer.constant = 0
    }
 }
```

Call it using :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("callToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)
```

Comment: The selector would be `#selector(toggleSideMenu)`, or `#selector(toggleSideMenu(_:))`, not `#selector(toggleSideMenu:)`.

Comment: @Nitish. do you have any reference for the above claim that function definition was not correct ?